# jquery and passing global variables

Tags: jquery, variables, global

I have the following:

```
window.linkFrom;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.linker").click(function(event){

            window.linkFrom = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");

            alert(window.linkFrom); 

            });

 });
```

and want to pass the var linkFrom to a different script on a second page:

```
window.linkFrom;

(document).ready(function(){    

            alert(window.linkFrom);

});
```

How do I make this work?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script environments of two different pages are entirely independent, so you cannot communicate over variables like this. Basically you have two choices:

1. Use cookies.
2. Modify the calls to the second page to add e.g. `#linkFrom=asdf` to the address and parse that in the js of the second page.

Clarifying edit: scripts -> script environments

Comment: Thanks Clacke.  What if I were to use the first script on both pages. Would the variable save from page to page?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. From one page load to another the scripting environment is reset, so you need to transfer the information through a side channel, like cookies or http fragments (the right-hand side of the `#`).